# Matching two data sets of different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, plot, scipy, signal-processing

I have two datasets with different sample rates and a different amount of samples, but both start at the same time and end at nearly the same time.
The first column of each dataset is time, how can I plot the second column of each against each other using the time column to match them but not have time on either axes?
Essentially I am trying to plot two vectors of different lengths against each other.

For example, have these two datasets, in the file named "temperature", the first column is time [s] and the second is temperature[°C].
The second file name "delay" has time [s] as the first column and a motor address as the second. 
I want to have temperature as my x-axis and the corresponding motor position as my y-axis.

[Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pCM1SRN3puJ7aL1OtHQMdnKStllwFG9M?usp=sharing)

I can't do a one to one match of the data because the time interval is different between the two, but as the sample rate is higher than I need it to be, it is okay if there is some local averaging on the data with more data points in order to have it be the same length.
I am using numpy arrays.

Comment: I haven't looked at the data, but could `zip` be what you're after? https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip

Comment: It would be very useful if you can put some visual cues for us to better understand your query.

Comment: @Jaxi 
I don't think so because then some the data wouldn't be used. The data with more points would be cut short
But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Ross Take a look at `pandas`. Just fill a DataFrame for each with the time as timestamp index with `parse_dates=True` and then resample both to the nearest matching frequency. Then you can merge both into one DataFrame. `pandas` is exactly the tool you are looking for for things like this.

Comment: Btw., your `delay.npy` is constant in the value column. Is this correct or is there an error in the file format?

Comment: @Scotty1
Okay, I'll look into that, thanks.
Yes you are right, out of numerous files I accidentally took one of the few where the motor didn't move, I have now replaced it with another file

Comment: Oh. Now the date column in `delay.npy` **has changed the format**! It seems to be an offset in seconds now.

Comment: I think [traces.TimeSeries.merge](https://traces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#traces.TimeSeries.merge) may do what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to work with irregularly spaced time series each day.uckily there are many nice tools for that in python. What, imho, stands out the most, is `pandas`, since it is using numpy arrays internally to store the data while offering a huge amount of time series based operations/calculations.
For working with timeseries, especially irregularly spaced timeseries, pandas is a great tool, since you can easily resample, interpolate etc. your data. (I am not connected to anyone of the pandas team, it just works the best in my experience.)

This is how I'd solve your problem, assuming the setting the resampling frequency to one second with `'1s'` is ok (since you stated that sampling freq. is much higher than needed, I guess it is ok...):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delay = np.load('delay.npy')  # load data. delay is constantly -14576.
temperature = np.load('temperature.npy')

df_delay = pd.DataFrame(  # load delay into DataFrame and convert timestamp
    data=delay[:, 1], index=pd.to_datetime(delay[:, 0], unit='s'))
date_offset = df_delay.index[0]  # same first timestamp as starting time for temperature
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(  # load temp. into df and convert relative timestamp using offset
    data=temperature[:, 1],
    index=pd.to_datetime(temperature[:, 0], unit='s', origin=date_offset))
# resample both to 1 second.
df_delay = df_delay.resample('1s').mean()
df_temp = df_temp.resample('1s').mean()
# merge both
df = pd.concat((df_delay, df_temp), axis=1)
df.columns = ['motor_position', 'temperature']  # name columns

plt.plot(df['temperature'], df['motor_position'])  # plot with matplotlib
```

If you want to use the (quite nice) plotting interface of pandas directly, you can also plot it with:

```
df.plot(x='temperature', y='motor_position')
```

If you want a higher frequency or make sure that an occasionally occurring low sampling frequency does not introduce `np.nan` into your data, append `.interpolate()` to the resampling:

```
df_delay = df_delay.resample('1s').mean().interpolate()
df_temp = df_temp.resample('1s').mean().interpolate()
```

For example for resampling to 100ms you can use `'100ms'` instead of `'1s'`.

If, like in the replaced `delay.npy` file, the timestamp is always in relative seconds, get the date offset with something like `date_offset = pd.to_datetime('201808201000')` and pass this to the creation of the delay dataframe with `origin=date_offset`.

Comment: This is ideal, I had never come across interpolating before so didn't even know what to search for.
You are also right that I changed the format of the time column in the data, I was trying to simplify the problem by removing the two different time formats as this was not the part I was having trouble with.

Comment: Yeah, luckily pandas makes interpolating etc. really easy. :) Well, now you can use both time formats, if you use the offset correctly.

Comment: Why does this work despite the vectors being different sizes?
For example:
plt.plot(df_temp, df_delay)
does not work, because the two vectors aren't the same size

Comment: If you plot after resampling, it should also work with `plt.plot(df_temp, df_delay)`. Maybe, depending on your date offset and the used fill method for resampling (in this case `mean()`), the first or last value of one of the time series may be np.nan or missing. So you can for example try `plt.plot(df_temp.iloc[1:], df_delay)` or drop the first row. With pandas this works, since I concatenated the time series before plotting. Thus both time series have the same size, the shorter time series is filled with nan to match the size of the longer time series.

Comment: Oh I see
Vielen Danke von München nach München =D

Comment: Gerne und viele Grüße von München nach München. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made some attempts yet? If so, please include the code - that is very helpful when trying to answer your question. Even pseudo code makes it much easier.

For your second dataset, do you know the reference or anchoring date/time? If it's simply counting in seconds, you won't be able to join to an absolute time. I assume  there *is* a starting time, so you could convert the 'time' column in the 'delay' dataset to a unix time value something like this:

```
import datetime
# arbitrarily define start date/time to be right now
start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
delay_datetime = start_datetime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time)
```

At this point you will have a 'datetime' column in both sets of data, and you can then join on datetime, which seems to be what you want to do.

Again, the above is semi-pseudo code, since I don't know if you are working with pandas dataframes, numpy arrays, etc., since there is no example code posted.

Comment: I have made attempts but I thought they would only add confusion as they didn't make sense because I don't know how one would go about doing this.
Regarding the time, I did the opposite and converted them both to start from zero, sorry I should have included that to begin with.
Also, I am using numpy arrays